# Better way of calling function in HTML angular

Tags: angular, typescript, function

I'm using Angular-10 and created one shared function as below (inside **dom.ts** file):

```
export function toSafeHtml(value) : any {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
}
```

And I want to call this wherever I have a [innerHtml] attributes. For example :

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    <div [innerHtml]="toSafeHtml(loaderTitle)"></div>
</div>
```

How to do this? Is there any better way to call the shared function directly in DOM?

Comment: What do you exactly want. and what your intension about **directly in DOM**

Comment: @er-sho I mean like this `[innerHtml]="toSafeHtml(loaderTitle)"` or any better way

Comment: I have posted my answer. kindly look into it and let me know

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to create a pipe.

**safe-html.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() {}
  transform(value: any) {
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, 'text/html').documentElement.textContent;
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    <div innerHtml="{{loaderTitle | safeHtml}}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether it is helpful?.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import * as fun from './function';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<p [innerHTML]="myFun.toSafeHtml(loaderTitle)"></p>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myFun = fun;
  loaderTitle = 'my-text'

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

and the function.ts in the same directory

```
export function toSafeHtml(value) : any {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
}
```

Comment: I don't want repeat the same for each and every component.

Comment: As I know HTML files are conned to the app through component.ts file. So, we have to update the conponent.ts if we use it in HTML

Answer (score 0):

You have to write wrapper method in your component ts file.

**your.component.ts**

```
wrapperToSafeHtml(value) {
  return toSafeHtml(value);
}
```

**your.component.html**

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
    <div [innerHtml]="wrapperToSafeHtml(loaderTitle)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @n-f But, in this case I have to write wrapper method in every component. It's repetitive correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You can not call function from html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the one trick here, so you don't need to write your `toSafeHtml` function again and again,

First create one service like

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class YourServiceName {

  toSafeHtml(value): any {
    return new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
  }
}
```

Then you have to add dependency in constructor of your component where you need to use above function

```
constructor(public yourServiceName: YourServiceName) {  
}
```

And then you can use it in you template like

```
<div [innerHtml]="yourServiceName.toSafeHtml(loaderTitle)"></div>
```

**Edit 1:**

> I don't want repeat the same for each and every component

You can also create a attribute directive to achieve your goal

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHtmlParser]'
})
export class HtmlParserDirective implements OnInit {

   @Input('html') html: any;
 
   constructor(private el: ElementRef) {    
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.textContent = this.toSafeHtml(this.html);
   }

   toSafeHtml(value): any {
        return new DOMParser().parseFromString(value, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
   }
}
```

And then you can use it in your template like

```
<div appHtmlParser [html]="loaderTitle"></div>
```

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff8krm?file=src/app/html-parser.directive.ts)**

Comment: I don't want repeat the same for each and every component.

Comment: @ShreekumarS, I have added an alternative, Kindly view **Edit 1** section.